# How to implement sort on specific atribute of object in custom sort function?

Tags: python, sorting, object

I'm trying to make quicksort to sort list of objects on one of the object's attribute. (for example Object of 2D point, sort on x or y)

I have a homework to write quicksort and heapsort, then use it on on list of 2d points.

QuickSort:

```
def quick_sort(a):  # interface
    quick_sort2(a, 0, len(a)-1)


def quick_sort2(a, low, high):  # split list
    if low < high:  # stop call for list of 1
        split = partition(a, low, high)  # split index
        quick_sort2(a, low, split-1)  # left side
        quick_sort2(a, split + 1, high)  # right side


def partition(a, low, high):  # setting the pivot
    pivot_idx = get_pivot(a, low, high)
    pivot_val = a[pivot_idx]
    a[pivot_idx], a[low] = a[low], a[pivot_idx]  # swap
    border = low

    for i in range(low, high+1):  # comparing to pivot
        if a[i] < pivot_val:
            border += 1
            a[i], a[border] = a[border], a[i]
    a[low], a[border] = a[border], a[low]
    return border


def get_pivot(a, low, high):  # selecting best pivot
    middle = (high + low) // 2
    pivot = high
    if a[low] < a[middle]:
        if a[middle] < a[high]:
            pivot = middle
    elif a[low] < a[high]:
        pivot = low
    return pivot
```

Point2D class:

```
class Point2D:
    def __init__(self, id_initial: int, x_initial: float, y_initial: float):

        self.id = id_initial
        self.x = x_initial
        self.y = y_initial

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._id

    @id.setter
    def id(self, value):
        self._id = value

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        self._y = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr((self._id, self._x, self._y))
```

this line will work for sorted():

```
QuickSort.quick_sort(mylist, key=lambda point: point.x)
```

I tried to find a solution for my custom sort function,
but no success, please help me...

Code for sorted():

```
mylist = []
for i in range(0, 3):
    x = random.randint(1, 10)
    y = random.randint(1, 10)
    mylist.append(Geometry.Point2D(i, x, y))

for point in mylist:
    print("P", point.id+1, "(", point.x, ",", point.y, ") ")

mylist2 = sorted(mylist, key=lambda point2d: point2d.x)

for point in mylist2:
    print("P", point.id+1, "(", point.x, ",", point.y, ") ")
```

Output:

```
P 1 ( 1 , 6 ) 
P 2 ( 9 , 9 ) 
P 3 ( 3 , 2 ) 
P 1 ( 1 , 6 ) 
P 3 ( 3 , 2 ) 
P 2 ( 9 , 9 )
```

Comment: You could try to add the standard operator functions https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html to your `class Point2D`. This enables you to define how to compare two classes an use a standard quicksort.

Comment: I have to use custom made quicksort/heapsort (if you mean that standard quicksort is built in one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a `key`, you'll have to modify your functions accordingly, by adding a `key` argument, and using it every time you compare elements of the list (e.g., `a[middle] < a[high]` should be `key(a[middle]) < key(a[high])`, or  `key(a[i]) < key(pivot_val)`, etc.):

As an example:

```
def default_key(x): # default key: use the value as-is
    return x

def quick_sort(a, key=default_key):  # accept keyword argument `key`
    quick_sort2(a, 0, len(a)-1, key=key) # pass on the key

def quick_sort2(a, low, high, key=default_key):
    if low < high:
        split = partition(a, low, high, key=key)  # pass the key
        quick_sort2(a, low, split-1, key=key)
        quick_sort2(a, split + 1, high, key=key)


def partition(a, low, high, key):
    pivot_idx = get_pivot(a, low, high, key=key)
    ...
        if key(a[i]) < key(pivot_val):
            ...


def get_pivot(a, low, high, key=default_key):  # selecting best pivot
...
    if key(a[low]) < key(a[middle]):
        if key(a[middle]) < key(a[high]):
...
```

Comment: something wrong with passing the key parameter, when I set `def quick_sort(a, key=default_key):
    return key(a[1])` I receive the x value, in other words lambda working but when I move the return line to `quick_sort2` I receive `None` @muru

Comment: I can't tell anything by that. Post your actual code

Comment: everything worked once I used print on `mylist` (sorted one) instead of using `mylist2`! Thank you! @muru

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a comparator to your class Poin2D `def __lt__(self,other)`.  This way the operator `<` in `getpivot()` knows how to compare two instances of the class Point2D.

```
class Point2D:
    def __init__(self, id_initial: int, x_initial: float, y_initial: float):
        self.id = id_initial
        self.x = x_initial
        self.y = y_initial

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.x < other.x

[...]
```

Afterwards you can call your function `quicksort()` like this:

```
mylist = []
for i in range(0, 5):
    x = random.randint(1, 10)
    y = random.randint(1, 10)
    mylist.append(Point2D(i, x, y))

for point in mylist:
    print("P", point.id + 1, "(", point.x, ",", point.y, ") ")

quick_sort(mylist)

print('x' * 20)
for point in mylist:
    print("P", point.id + 1, "(", point.x, ",", point.y, ") ")
```

Comment: From what I understood it doesn't let me choose on which field of the object i want to sort the list during the call quick_sort(list,field), Am I right?

Comment: yes you are right. the set of functions defined here (https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions) defines how operators for two instances should be intepreted.